# t-sql insert from select with random value subquery

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, select, random, insert

I am building a piece of code so that a person can control room assignments for an apartment complex. What they want is to be able to randomly assign room numbers to all tenants for a specific college semester. The problem I am running into is that my subquery which selects the random room number is the same for all tenants after the insert completes.

I have a table with the rooms and available spots in the room. When I run the select statement as a whole outside of the insert statement it works just fine, returning random room numbers every time for each tenant but the insert statement does not. Any ideas why?

Here is the code for the insert statement.

```
   INSERT INTO Rooms_Semester (UserId, SemesterId, RoomId, LastUpdatedBy) 
        SELECT u.Id, @SemesterId, 
                    (SELECT TOP 1 r.Id 
                     FROM Rooms r 
                     WHERE (SELECT COUNT(rs.RoomId) 
                            FROM Rooms_Semester rs 
                            WHERE rs.RoomId = r.Id) <= r.NumberOfRooms
                       AND r.RoomNumber IS NOT NULL 
                     ORDER BY NEWID())
            , 1 
        FROM [User] u 
            JOIN [Order] o 
              ON o.User_Id = u.Id 
            JOIN OrderItem oi 
              ON oi.Order_Id = o.Id 
             AND oi.Product_Id = @SemesterId
            LEFT JOIN Rooms_Semester rs 
              ON rs.UserId = u.Id
        WHERE oi.Product_Id = @SemesterId 
              AND LOWER(oi.Status) = 'tenant' 
              AND rs.RoomId IS NULL
```

Comment: Which version of Sql Server is that?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
INSERT INTO Rooms_Semester (UserId, SemesterId, RoomId, LastUpdatedBy) 
select a.id, a.SemesterId, b.id, 1 
from 
(
SELECT u.Id, @SemesterId SemesterId, row_number() over (order by newid()) rn
FROM [User] u JOIN [Order] o ON o.User_Id = u.Id JOIN OrderItem oi ON 
oi.Order_Id = o.Id AND oi.Product_Id = @SemesterId
LEFT JOIN Rooms_Semester rs ON rs.UserId = u.Id
WHERE oi.Product_Id = @SemesterId AND LOWER(oi.Status) = 'tenant' AND rs.RoomId IS NULL
) a
left join 
(SELECT Id, row_number() over (order by id) rn FROM Rooms where RoomNumber IS NOT NULL) b
on b.rn = a.rn
```

Since i don't have your tables, i have been unable to test it.